# Dropzone.js is not opening file chooser in samsung default browsers

Tags: dropzone.js

I have implemented dropzone in my website like

```
myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
              url:"$uploadUrl",
              timeout:0, 
              acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.webp",
              dictDefaultMessage:"Drag & Drop or Select Photos",
              addRemoveLinks:true,
              renameFile:function (file) {return new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name;},
              clickable:true,
              headers: {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              },
         });
```

Above is the code.And it is working fine in chrome and all. But in some devices for example Samsung s9 default browser i cant select files, meaning there is no file chooser coming when clicking the dropzone.

```
i am using dropzone 5.7.0
```